# create new variables on string contents

Tags: regex, r

If I have these strings:

```
dat <- data.frame(xxs = c("PElookx.PElookxstd","POaftGx.POlookGxstd"))
```

how can I create a new variable where for instance if the string contains `PE` I want `NOW` or `PO` I would get `LATER`

```
newxxs <- (`NOW`,`LATER`)
```

I kind of know how to use grep to do this:

```
dat$newxss <- NA
dat$newxss[grep("PE",dat$xxs)] <- "NOW"
dat$newxss[grep("PO",dat$xxs)] <- "LATER"
```

Is there a easier way than lots of `grep`s? As I will have to do this for multiple bits of strings for the same new column and for many new columns.

Comment: Do all your strings definitely have a `PE` or `PO`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have different substitutions to do, you can create a custom function to do them all at once, for example :

```
subst <- function(var, corresp) {
  sapply(corresp, function(elem) {
    var[grep(elem[1],var)] <- elem[2]
  })
}

var <- c("PEfoo", "PObar", "PAfoofoo", "PUbarbar")
corresp <- list(c("PE","NOW"),
                c("PO","LATER"),
                c("PA", "MAYBE"),
                c("PU", "THE IPHONE IS IN THE BLENDER"))
subst(var, corresp)
```

Will give :

```
[1] "NOW"                          "LATER"                       
[3] "MAYBE"                        "THE IPHONE IS IN THE BLENDER"
```

So you can repeatedly apply your function to different columns of your data frame :

```
dat$new1 <- subst(dat$old1, corresp1)
dat$new2 <- subst(dat$old2, corresp2)
dat$new3 <- subst(dat$old3, corresp3)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If all your strings **definitely** have a `PE` or `PO` in it, you can use `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(grepl("PE", dat$xxs), "NOW", "LATER")
```

**Example:**

```
set.seed(45)

x <- sample(c("PEx", "POy"), 20, replace=T)
# [1] "POy" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx" "POy" "PEx" "PEx" 
#         "PEx" "POy" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx" "POy" "PEx" "PEx" "PEx"

ifelse(grepl("PE", x), "NOW", "LATER")

# [1] "LATER" "NOW"   "NOW"   "NOW"   "NOW"   "NOW"   "NOW"   "LATER" "NOW"   
#         "NOW"   "NOW"   "LATER" "NOW"   "NOW"   "NOW"  
# [16] "NOW"   "LATER" "NOW"   "NOW"   "NOW"
```